# In DataGrip error messages, what does "position" mean?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datagrip

**Background**

I'm doing some error debugging on a big PostgreSQL query someone's helped me out with. I work in DataGrip, I'm trying to use the error messages to help me out (like in any programming GUI).

**The Problem**

The issue is that it's telling me that the error's occurring at a certain "position", but it's not clear from anything in the GUI or the DataGrip documentation what that means. Here's a sample error message:

[image]

But as I look around my screen, all I see in terms of indicators of where my cursor is is the line and column indicator in the bottom-right:

[image]

In that screenshot, I'm on like 464 and column 25 of my current console.

Anyone have an idea? This feels frustratingly novice, but I'm stuck.

Comment: It also tells you about an error, `[42P01] ERROR: relation "an" does not exist`, try to find its reference and see if that helps you to resolve it.

Comment: Yes, I've looked around for that, but the query's very long and contains many references to that alias `an`, hence my wondering if I can narrow things down my getting to that "position" somehow.

Comment: I see, in such a case, I would go for joining to the line and try to find the reference at that position in that joined line. Another option, if the query is split into smaller queries, which can be run independently, try running on a dev DB.

Comment: I'm going to say position is 2164 characters in. Run the query in `psql` and you will get something like: `select * from an; ERROR:  relation "an" does not exist LINE 1: select * from an;`. Where a caret(^) will show the error position.

Comment: This message should be clickable: the click will navigate you to the corresponding position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use F2 to navigate to an error

Answer (score 1):

Note: For semantic errors like type comparison errors, the "F2" method won't work. E.g.

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = text
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types.
You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 1015
```

I'm fairly sure DataGrip only recognises and enumerates syntax errors, so F2 won't work for these. I haven't found how to see cursor character position in DataGrip, so I copy and paste the query out into Notepad++ instead as it has all three cursor positional values: line, column, position:

[image]

Seems like a bit of an oversight by the devs...